# Exception in callback AgnosticLatentCommandCursor

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, python-asyncio, tornado-motor

I am using python aiohttp, asyncio and motor(mongo async client) for my web service. From my logs, I frequently notice the below 3 lines of errors which are repetitive in random intervals. I could not associate this to any specific API calls as there's no stacktrace tracing from API.

[image]

May I know the cause of this error and possible solutions?

Comment: It would help if you could create a minimal example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: seems it is something to do with the `motor` library, but as user4815162342 mentions, some code or a minimal example would go a long way